# Why will jQuery not apply to javascript generated html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a JS function called `getImages` that loads in this html:

```js
// Begining of funtion
function getImages() {
    $.getJSON(GETIMAGELIST, function(data) {
        var items = [];

// html populate
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<div class="post-container">');
    items.push('<div class="post-heading-container">');
    items.push('<div class="username-container plain-text">');
    items.push('<p>' + val["userName"] + '</p>');
    items.push('</div>');
    items.push('<div class="actions-container">');
    items.push('<button class="post-action-btn" id="post-action-btn">');
    items.push('<span class="fas" id="menu-icon"></span>');
    items.push('</button>');
    items.push('<div class="action-menu-container glass-effect" id="action-menu-container">');
    items.push('<div class="menu-option-row">');
    items.push('<button class="menu-action-btn small-text">Leave a comment</button>');
    items.push('</div>');
    items.push('</div>');
    items.push('</div>');
    items.push('<div class="clearFix"></div>');
    items.push('</div>');
    items.push('<div class="post-content-container">');
    items.push("<img src='" + BLOB_ACCOUNT + val["filePath"] + "' class='uploaded-file'/>");
    items.push('</div>');
    items.push('<div class="post-info-container plain-text">');
    items.push('<span class="username">' + val["userName"] + ': </span>');
    items.push('<span class="post-name">' + val["fileName"] + '</span>');
    items.push('</div>');
    items.push('<div class="comment-section">');
    items.push('<div class="comment-content small-text">');
    items.push('<span class="username">username: </span>');
    items.push('<span class="comment">comment 1</span>');
    items.push('</div>');
    items.push('</div>');
    items.push('</div>');
});

// End of function
$('#ImageList').empty();

$("<ul/>", {
    "class": "posts",
    html: items.join("")
}).appendTo("#ImageList");
```

The HTLM when loaded in looks like this:

```html
<div class="posts">
    <div class="post-container">
        <div class="post-heading-container">
            <div class="username-container plain-text">
                <p>Username</p> 
            </div>

            <div class="actions-container">
                <button class="post-action-btn" id="post-action-btn">
                    <span class="fas" id="menu-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="action-menu-container glass-effect" id="action-menu-container">
                    <div class="menu-option-row">
                        <button class="menu-action-btn small-text">Leave a comment</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clearFix"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="post-content-container"></div>

        <div class="post-info-container plain-text">
            <span class="username">username:</span>
            <span class="post-name">post title</span>
        </div>

        <div class="comment-section">
            <div class="comment-content small-text">
                <span class="username">username:</span>
                <span class="comment">comment 1</span>
            </div>

            <div class="comment-content small-text">
                <span class="username">username:</span>
                <span class="comment">comment 2</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the HTML is statically generated, just typed into `index.html`, the result is:

[image]

When the HTML is dynamically generated, through the `getImages` func, the result is:

[image]

You can see that the jQuery will not load in the ellipsis when dynamically called but will when statically called. Why is this?

Here is the jQuery that loads in the ellipsis:

```js
$("#menu-icon").addClass("fa-ellipsis-h"); // Menu ellipsis


// This jQuery is the code that changes the menu icon in the first screenshot
$("#post-action-btn").click(function() {
    if (menu_open == false) {
        // Fading in the Action Menu on click
        $("#action-menu-container").fadeIn();
        $("#menu-icon").removeClass("fa-ellipsis-h");
        $("#menu-icon").addClass("fa-times");
        menu_open = true
    } else if (menu_open == true) {
        $("#action-menu-container").fadeOut();
        $("#menu-icon").removeClass("fa-times");
        $("#menu-icon").addClass("fa-ellipsis-h");
        menu_open = false
    }
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fix was simple, all I had to do was move the jQuery inside of the `getImages()` func